# To do a call back function in TraCIScenarioManager

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am writing a Server Client Program where omnet/veins is the client. However, omnet doesn't request data but acts on the data sent from the server. I want to keep listening for a message from the server but also allow other events to happen simultaneously without causing any delay in the execution of the events. I am using TraCIScenarioManager module to wait for the data from the server.

Comment: Your question does not really ask a question, but let me point you to The INET Framework, which has an example of how to react to external events using a special scheduler for OMNeT++

Comment: Hello Christoph Sommer, Thank you for your reply. Could you please point me out which example I need to refer to? What I would like to do is I want to schedule events based on data from the server. Also, when the events are happening, I also want to listen if I have received any data through the socket connection. Whenever I receive a data from the server, based on the data I would like to call a respective call back function which schedules an event for a particular time.

Comment: Take a look at the Sockets example from OMNeT++ itself if you are interested in feeding your simulation with data from external sources over a socket connection.

Comment: I followed the example of sockets of omnet to create my own scheduler and I edited the TraCIConnection file present in the src folder of veins to convert it into a scheduler by inheriting cScheduler.I have included the class TraCIConnection in omnetpp.ini file.However, when I try to run the simulation, I get the following error: " Class TraCIConnection" not found -- perhaps it's code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(),or in the case of modules and channels with Define_Module()/Define_Channel().Can you please guide me how can I resolve this problem?